# CSS: Centering/Aligning image within div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center an image within a div.
The div contains an img element and an h3 element.
Here is the code from JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/johngoche99/jvkG4/6/

```
img { text-align: center; }
div { width: 400px; background: yellow; }

<div>
    <image alt="Hello" src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSpxx-IcjRJjDCKXZ6y4eMcUkShjBB_U_Y8OOy8nRR_qT9-ZgG24A" />
    <h3>Hello World Hello World Hello World</h1>
<div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/jvkG4/15/).

Comment: text-align: center; on your div, not your image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
div { width: 400px;
      background: yellow;
      text-align: center; 
     }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    try this

        div { width: 400px; background: yellow; text-align: center;  }
    img { }

<div>
    <image alt="Hello" src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSpxx-IcjRJjDCKXZ6y4eMcUkShjBB_U_Y8OOy8nRR_qT9-ZgG24A" />
    <h3>Hello World Hello World Hello World</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

**1/** `<div>` has end tag `</div>` not `<div>`...

**2/** if you want to align stuff(**image** in this case) in the **div** just set the `text-align: center` to the **div**.

**3/** Also: `<h3>Hello World Hello World Hello World</h1>` doesn't look valid X_X
decide what kind of header you want and go for:

```
<h1>My header</h1>
```

or

```
<h3>My header</h3>
```

**4/** Study CSS little bit more here for example here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/

Answer (score 2):

```
<div><center>
  <image alt="Hello" src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSpxx-  IcjRJjDCKXZ6y4eMcUkShjBB_U_Y8OOy8nRR_qT9-ZgG24A" />
   <h3>Hello World Hello World Hello World</h1>
   <center>
<div>
```

Tested in JSFiddle

Answer (score 2):

```
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSpxx-IcjRJjDCKXZ6y4eMcUkShjBB_U_Y8OOy8nRR_qT9-ZgG24A" style=" display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;"/>
```

This will work. Just tested in JSfiddle.

Comment: This also makes it extensible. Enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div style="text-align:center"><img src="" /></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this, or do you want it in another way?
http://jsfiddle.net/jvkG4/11/

```
<div>
```

Hello World Hello World Hello World

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
img { display: block; margin: 0 auto }
div { width: 400px; background: yellow; }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two methods of doing this.

## Updating the Image to Display Block

```
img { margin: 0 auto; width: 120px; display: block; }
div { width: 400px; background: yellow; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jvkG4/18/

## Keeping the Image Inline Display

```
img { }
div { width: 400px; background: yellow; text-align: center; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jvkG4/17/